# Xcode 9.2: Size Discrepancy between Release builds inside Xcode and using xcodebuild

Tags: xcode, clang, xcode9, xcodebuild, strip

It appears that when building with Xcode 9.2, binaries generated with `xcodebuild` are slightly larger than by using Xcode's regular 'Build for Profiling' command. Both are set to generate Release builds, the configuration for command-line builds is also set to 'Release' and this did not occur with previous versions of Xcode.

These are the frameworks with their respective sizes when building from within Xcode:

[image]

And these are generated by `xcodebuild`:

[image]

I suspect that some debug or code coverage data is left in some of the frameworks when using `xcodebuild`.

FYI: A previous build had way larger C binaries (e.g. sqlite3.framework was several megabytes in size). After discovering https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/2056, I disabled code coverage in the 'Test' action of my build scheme and disabled the "Undefined Behavior" sanitizer. Before that, the frameworks were even larger (again, note sqlite3.framework) and there was a dylib from the "Undefined Behavior" sanitizer which should not be present in Release builds:

[image]

**Did anyone encounter something similar and/or was able to fix this issue? Happy to provide the output of e.g. `nm` or `otool` if that helps (and you tell me which options to pass to those tools to generate meaningful information).**

P.S.:
I am using this command for `xcodebuild`:

```
xcodebuild -workspace Timing.xcworkspace -scheme 'Timing 2' -configuration 'Release' -derivedDataPath build clean build
```

I did enable parallel builds with

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode BuildSystemScheduleInherentlyParallelCommandsExclusively -bool NO
```

and am using the new Xcode build system, however the issue also appears with the "regular" build settings. Plus, there should not be a difference between the outputs of Xcode's build step and `xcodebuild` in either case. Also, sqlite3.framework is built via CocoaPods, but that should not matter, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the extra data was code coverage data injected due to `xcodebuild` adding the compiler options `-profile-generate -profile-coverage-mapping`. The "solution" was to uncheck the "Gather coverage data" option on the "Test" scheme action, even though `xcodebuild` was not building for testing.